# Solving for a function in a definite integral

Tags: calculus

I have a challenge on how to solve the following problem.

Find all continuous positive functions $f$ (if any) defined on $[0,1]$ so that
$$\int^1_0 f(x)\sin(\pi x)\,dx = a$$

where $a$ is a given real number.

My confusion is in the fact that the question is to find all continuous positive functions.

If I am suggesting that $f(x)$ be a constant $C$, so that I have a particular solution for $f(x)$, would that suffice for the required answer?

Kindly help me out.

Comment: That would not be sufficient. You have to show that these are the only functions, e.g. for any other function the formula does not hold, which seems rather unlikely.

Comment: For example, for any continuous function $f$, you can compute the integral and multiply $f$ by $a$ divided by the integral

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be any continuous function on $[0,1]$.
Then $C:=\int_0^1 f(x)\sin(\pi x)dx$ is finite and the function
$$\tilde f(x)=\frac{a}{C}f(x)$$
satisfies the required condition.
If you require $\tilde f$ to be positive, you have to be careful with the sign, but maybe you can figure out by yourself how to get around this problem to have a sufficient condition for $\tilde f$ to be positive.

It is a good exercise.